# Помогите, как сделать так чтобы нейронка могла писать сообщение с несколькими строками

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sklearn

Вот код:

````
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

bot = telebot.TeleBot('нет')

wikipedia.set_lang("ru")

def clean_str(r):
    r = r.lower()
    r = [c for c in r if c in alphabet]
    return ''.join(r)

alphabet = ' 1234567890-йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюёqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm?%.,()!:;"«»'

def update():
    with open('dialogues.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
    
    blocks = content.split('\n')
    dataset = []
    
    for block in blocks:
        replicas = block.split('\\')[:2]
        if len(replicas) == 2:
            pair = [clean_str(replicas[0]), clean_str(replicas[1])]
            if pair[0] and pair[1]:
                dataset.append(pair)
    
    X_text = []
    y = []
    
    for question, answer in dataset[:10000]:
        X_text.append(question)
        y += [answer]
    
    global vectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_text)
    
    global clf
    clf = LogisticRegression()
    clf.fit(X, y)

update()

def get_generative_replica(text):
    text_vector = vectorizer.transform([text]).toarray()[0]
    question = clf.predict([text_vector])[0]
    return question

def getwiki(s):
    try:
        ny = wikipedia.page(s)
        wikitext=ny.content[:1000]
        wikimas=wikitext.split('.')
        wikimas = wikimas[:-1]
        wikitext2 = ''
        for x in wikimas:
            if not('==' in x):
                if(len((x.strip()))>3):
                   wikitext2=wikitext2+x+'.'
            else:
                break
        wikitext2=re.sub('\([^()]*\)', '', wikitext2)
        wikitext2=re.sub('\([^()]*\)', '', wikitext2)
        wikitext2=re.sub('\{[^\{\}]*\}', '', wikitext2)
        return wikitext2
    except Exception as e:
        return 'В энциклопедии нет информации об этом'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Здравствуйте, Сэр.")

question = ""

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    command = message.text.lower()
    if command =="не так":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "а как?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, wrong)
    else:
        global question
        question = command
        reply = get_generative_replica(command)
        if reply=="вики ":
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, getwiki(command))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, reply)

def wrong(message):
    a = f"{question}\{message.text.lower()} \n"
    with open('dialogues.txt', "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(a)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Готово")
    update()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
Прикол его в том что если сообщение будет с 3 или двумя строчками то он пишет только первую. Можно это как то исправить
````

Comment: Прикол его в том что если сообщение будет с 3 или двумя строчками то он пишет только первую. Можно это как то исправить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.